# handleChange is not defined no-undef in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

handleChange is not defined no-undef showing this when rum=n page in react

```
function ApplicationCategories() {
      const options = ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Europe"];
      handleChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log(value);
      };
      return (
        <SecureLayout>
            <ReactSelectMaterialUi
              style={{ width: 100 }}
              value="Europe"
              options={options}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        </SecureLayout>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use react functions you need to declare inner function with const or let. And you don't need to use this then. It's not a class anymore.

```js
function ApplicationCategories() {
      const options = ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Europe"];
      const handleChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log(value);
      };
      return (
        <SecureLayout>
            <ReactSelectMaterialUi
              style={{ width: 100 }}
              value="Europe"
              options={options}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </SecureLayout>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onChange={handleChange}` not `onChange={this.handleChange}` because you want to pass the reference of a function that is defined in the function body. `this.something` is used when you want to access a class property.

```
handleChange = (event, value) => {
   console.log(value);
};
```

The above snippet is used to declare methods in a class.

Since you want to declare a function inside a function's body it should be

```
const handleChange = (event, value) => {
   console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: @TusharKumawat Did you make both the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `functional component`. It is also called `stateless component`.

So the `method` should be defined using `const/let`. And while calling don't use `this`.

```
function ApplicationCategories() {
      const options = ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Europe"];
      
      const handleChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log(value);
      };

      return (
        <SecureLayout>
            <ReactSelectMaterialUi
              style={{ width: 100 }}
              value="Europe"
              options={options}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </SecureLayout>
      );
    }
```

Comment: This is not defined in that scope. So just declare the function as a variable var/const/let. Now it's within the scope of the function. Also, the variable needs either of the above modifiers(const/let/var). Then it should work @TusharKumawat

Comment: @TusharKumawat Ideally it should work if you are using functional component. Can you tell me what you have changed in your code?